# How Can I Count the Number of Times a User has Logged on to a OpenLdap Domain

Tags: macos, openldap

I am using openLdap server for centralised authentication.I wanted to count number of times all clients have logined against this openLdapserver. On googling i found that Logoncount is there for Active Directory but didnt find anything for openldap. Any help is appreciable.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported directly in the user entry. You would have to enable the access log overlay and scan the access logs yourself.

Comment: I want to know if any attribute is there that can count number of logins, just like it showing number of unsucessful attempts.As i want to use the number of logins some where else , i want it to get the value without manual monitoring.